# Which styles belong to the HTML-element 'a'?

Tags: html, css, performance, styles

My question: "Which styles belong to the HTML-element 'a'?"
And, is in my example everything right?

I've got these **styles**:

```
h1 {
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    text-align: center;
}
h1 a {
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'x';
    font-size: 37px;
    line-height: 49px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

And (of course) this **HTML-Code**:

```
<h1>
    <a href="y">bla bla</a>
</h1>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear.

Comment: from my experience, you can stuff about anything into `<a>` and it will work. In most cases, anyway.

Comment: Based on your question it's the second rule.

Comment: I would advise to use a tool like firebug or the developer tools of chrome to find all the styles which are actually applied to the »a«.

Comment: @programminginallston: Did I put the right styles into the right element?

Comment: i believe all those styles could be put on either element - certainly looks ok
the border on the h1 will default to full page width, on the <a> it would just surround the text

Comment: @imma: Yeah right, but it's only a section of my code and so the elements are in a container ;-)

Comment: @dystroy: I'm so sorry, 10 others understood ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only styles you need to worry about are `color` and `text-decoration`.  All other styles are inherited from the parent.  `color` and `text-decoration`, however, will be overridden by the `a` to make the link blue and underlined.  Therefore, the `color` and `text-decoration` must be applied to the `a` directly, or set to `inherit`.

I can't say it's "right" or "wrong", because that is subjective.  If it brings the desired results in the browser then it works.

Comment: It is really not true, the specificity of the `h1 a` CSS also gives the `a` a size, line height etc. applied to the `a` element.

Comment: what i meant is that those styles can be inherited if not specified, where as color and text-decoration will not be inherited.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like perfectly valid CSS to me.

If you are unsure of your syntax, you can always use the [CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input) in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is that both will be affected but anything targeting the anchor tag (your 'a' link) will override your H1 styles.  So if I said, h1 { color: red; } and then said h1 a { color: blue; } then the link color would end up blue because it's the most targeted style.  Your code looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

All of the styles will be applied to that HTML, but only the second style (`h1 a`) will be applied specifically to the link nested in the `<h1>` tag, if you remove that `<a>` tag then the second style will not be applied.